# Windows 7 Audio Glitching

Tags: windows-7, audio

Dozens of times throughout the day my audio glitches at random, just for a split second. It happens in Grooveshark and Spotify, but I haven't tested any other audio players.

My PC is a brand new Dell Precision laptop, i7 processor, 8GB ram, solid state drive, fully updated. In the device manager under "Sound, video and game controllers" there are two devices listed, "AMD High Definition Audio Device" and "IDT High Definition Audio CODEC". I confirmed they are both using the most up to date drivers.

I tried looking at the event logs and didn't notice anything out of the ordinary and was unable to correlate any event to the glitching. It almost seems like spikes in the processor usage are interfering with the audio service.

I really don't even know where to start on this one. Any suggestions?